# Why does the Google log-in fail with http-headers?

Tags: express, http-headers, content-security-policy, helmet.js

Currently I'm working on an application with a frontend and backend. I want to implement secure http-headers, especially Content Security Policy. But now the problem is, that the Google Sign In doesn't work anymore. As soon as I can choose which Account to log-in nothing happens anymore.

I've added HelmetJS and changed these CSP setting in my backend with ExpressJS:

```
defaultSrc: [
          "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'www.google.com' 'www.gstatic.com'",
        ],
        scriptSrc: [
          '"self" "unsafe-eval" "unsafe-inline" "google" "*.google" "*.google.com" "*.googleapis.com"',
        ],
```

I tried adding google to allowed domains but it didn't work.

Comment: Try flipping the single and double qoutes for scriptSrc. If it doesn't help include some error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're quoting things you shouldn't. Things like "self" and "unsafe-inline" should be quoted, but others shouldn't.

Try this:

```
defaultSrc: [
  // Should be quoted
  "'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'",
  // Shouldn't be quoted
  "www.google.com", "www.gstatic.com",
],
scriptSrc: [
  // Should be quoted
  "'self'", "'unsafe-eval'", "'unsafe-inline'",
  // Shouldn't be quoted
  "*.google", "*.google.com", "*.googleapis.com",
],
```